# How does other end understand what is my external ip if RTCPeerConnection.createOffer() says only my local ip?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I do:

```js
configuration = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: [
        'stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302',
      ],
    },
  ],
  iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
};

local_conn = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
local_offer = await local_conn.createOffer()
local_conn.setLocalDescription(local_offer)

console.log(local_conn)
{type: "offer", sdp: "v=0 ↵o=- 5782587598134818591 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1 ↵s=- ↵t=0 0 ↵a=msid-semantic: WMS ↵"}
```

IN IP4 127.0.0.1 why is it 127.0.0.1, not my external ip like 151.101.1.69?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ICE Candidate includes IP address infomation.

Comment: But setLocalDescription retrieves your external IP from a STUN server, isn't that?

Comment: Yes that is correct Cookie! It sends a STUN Binding Request to the server you passed in your `urls`.